# like creeping socialism, this will become second nature to you -- what does that really mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Source: [C++ For Dummies, 7th Edition](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-111882377X.html) by Stephen R. Davis (2014)

Example:

> A cheat sheet that provides an overview of C++ grammar in one (fairly)
>   easy to read page is available at www.dummies.com/cheatsheet/
>   cplusplus. Beginners will want to print this out and keep it handy as
>   they work through the later chapters. **Like creeping socialism**, eventually
>   C++ syntax will become second nature and you won’t need the cheat
>   sheet anymore.

What point exactly is he trying to make? Is this a cultural reference to something?

Comment: Yes, a cultural reference. Right-wing politicians and their adherents in the West love to complain how socialism is "creeping in" to gain more power through new legislation (state-funded healthcare, pensions, subsidies to environmentally clean companies etc.). It's a jokey book you're reading, it's shot through with such references to ease the process of learning.

Comment: Analogous to the live frog in the pot of water that is only slowly brought to a boil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds to me like a weak attempt at political commentary, perhaps trying to make a joke. The implication is that "creeping socialism" has become second nature for the country (probably talking about the US).

*Creeping socialism* is a kind of buzzword or idiomatic phrase used by conservatives to describe a gradual trend towards socialist or authoritarian policies. The idea is that over time a government is given more and more regulatory power, creates more and more taxes, and spends more and more money.

*Second nature* means something that comes naturally, but which is an acquired skill and not an inborn talent. A skill that is second nature requires little to no conscious effort.

It's a bizarre analogy to make because creeping socialism is not a skill, but I think the point the author is *trying* to make is that our political process creates socialist policies without thinking about it.